# how to code to draw a trend line from lowest point to highest point between start time and end time (means in a certain time range) in pine script

Tags: pine-script

how to code to draw a trend line from lowest point to highest point between start time  and end time (means in a certain time range) in pine script

```
@version=4
strategy("TESTMy Strategy", overlay=true)


startDate = input(title="Start Date", type=input.integer, defval=20, minval=1, maxval=23)
startMonth = input(title="Start Month", type=input.integer, defval=7, minval=1, maxval=12)
startYear = input(title="Start Year", type=input.integer, defval=2021, minval=1800, maxval=2100)

endDate = input(title="End Date", type=input.integer, defval=31, minval=1, maxval=31)
endMonth = input(title="End Month", type=input.integer, defval=08, minval=1, maxval=12)
endYear = input(title="End Year", type=input.integer, defval=2021, minval=1800, maxval=2100)
```

Comment: Hi, please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Good luck 

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.